# How to modify styles extracted from KML in OpenLayers4

Tags: openlayers

I'm using OpenLayers4 to load and display a 3rd party's KML.  I need to retain the original styles (colors, opacity, icons, etc), but I need to change the icon sizes.  Is there any way to modify the styles which get extracted or should I focus on the sharedStyles or is there a more appropriate way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone stumbles on this, I thought it would be nice to share.  I ran into several issues and decided the most straightforward solution was to just modify the XML myself before using it in the OpenLayers library.

After creating my map, mapview, and any other layers, I call LoadKML with the URL of the KML I need to display.  Once the KML is loaded/parsed, I modify it; got lazy and used jQuery on the document rather than hand-rolling a lot of CRUD functions.  Once the KML was updated, I used OpenLayers functions to read & apply styles and features.

The following is ONLY a general idea and is missing pieces not related to my problem so do not just copy/paste and expect this to work:

```
function LoadKML(urlStr) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('GET', urlStr, true);

    xhr.onload = function(event) {
        if(!!xhr.status || xhr.status >= 200 && xhr.status < 300) {
            var source = xhr.responseXML;
            if(!source) {
                //parse the xhr.responseText somehow
                //You can create a DOMParser, use jQuery.parseXML, ol.xml.parse, etc
                source = ol.xml.parse(xhr.responseText);
            }
            if(source) {
                fixXML(source);
                ProcessAsKML(source);
            }
        }
    }

    xhr.send();
}

function fixXML(xmlDoc) {
    //At this point, you have an XMLDocument
    //Do something with it...
    //... Change styles, handle nested MultiGeometry nodes, etc ...
}

function ProcessAsKML(kmlSourceDoc) {
    var kmlFormat = new ol.format.KML({
        showPointNames: true
    });

    //mapView is defined elsewhere and is the VIEW for my map
    var kmlFeatures = kmlFormat.readFeatures(kmlSourceDoc, {
        dataProjection: ol/proj.get('EPSG:4326'),
        featureProjection: mapView.getProjection()
    });

    var kmlSource = new ol.source.Vector({
        format: kmlFormat,
        features: kmlFeatures
    });

    var kmlLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
        source: kmlSource
    });

    myMap.addLayer(kmlLayer);
}
```

It's not perfect (neither am I), but it's working really well and I can move on.